# Modify default kernel module

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I need to debug an existing kernel driver (added to the kernel with menuconfig before kernel compilation). I intend to use printk statements to see what happens there, but in order to do that I need to remove the module from the kernel, rebuild it as a loadable module and load it. Is this possible and how? Do I need to rebuild the whole kernel without this module and then install it? If so - is there something special about the make file for the module?

Sorry if this is a newbie question :)

Best Regards
Ivo

Comment: Yes. Yes. And dunno, probably not, but i can't be sure because you never told us the module name.

Comment: Sorry for this lack of information.
The particular module is for linux-sunxi. Path to it in kernel build directory is: drivers/spi/spi_sunxi.c

In Github:

https://github.com/linux-sunxi/linux-sunxi/blob/sunxi-3.4/drivers/spi/spi_sunxi.c